# How to pass a USB device that is not found in linux to a VirtualBox directly

Tags: usb, virtualbox

I have a `Playertek` usb device that from what i can tell is only valid for windows or a Mac.

I plug the device in an there are no new devices seen in : `lsusb`

```
hutber@hutber:~$ lsusb 
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 2109:0813 VIA Labs, Inc. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 2109:2813 VIA Labs, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04e8:347e Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05e3:0732 Genesys Logic, Inc. All-in-One Cardreader
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 05e3:0620 Genesys Logic, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 17e9:6006 DisplayLink 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 05e3:0620 Genesys Logic, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 0b05:18a3 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 014: ID 1532:0045 Razer USA, Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 045e:07a5 Microsoft Corp. Wireless Receiver 1461C
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 1b1c:0c04 Corsair 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0922:001f Dymo-CoStar Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 06c4:c411 Bizlink International Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 008: ID b58e:9e84 Blue Microphones Yeti Stereo Microphone
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Is it possible to see all plugged in devices, even if not recognized by the OS and pass this device directly to my Windows 10 VM?

Comment: You need to determine its VID and PID on real windows with [USBDeview](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html) and then locate the device in `lsusb` output.

Comment: I assume then, the Genesys Logic, Inc. Are devices that Linux does not reconise?

Comment: Guessing is not a method here, I'll recommend to get PID and VID in Windows first. The `lsusb` may not know some [ids](http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids).

Comment: Indeed. Then more my question was, is it possible that the device is not currently listed by `lsusb`? This list did not change when plugging/unplugging the device. Either way, I will get the PID and VID. Thanks very much for helping